# Is it valid to apply col-xx and hidden-xx classes to the same div?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it valid to apply `col-xx-##` and `hidden-xx` classes to the same div? For example,

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-3 hidden-xs"></div>
```

That is, is the preceding equivalent to the following?

```
<div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it valid to apply `col-xx-##` and `hidden-xx` classes to the same div?

It's nonsensical in that trying to set the width of an invisible column makes no sense.
It's "valid" in the sense that it doesn't cause any collateral damage beyond the `col-xx-##` having no effect.

> That is, is the preceding equivalent to the following?
>
> `<div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs"></div>`

Yes. The `hidden-*` classes use `!important`, so they'll dominate over the `col-*` classes.

Answer (score 0):

First example is useless, but technically "valid". Your second block (`class="col-md-6 hidden-xs"`) has exactly the same effect with less overhead.